# How to parse a whitespace character with Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, utf-8

I get a string from an outer app. The string is non-ASCII for example: `1 Один`.

When I use this `$str =~ /^1(.{1})/; print Dumper($1)` I get `$VAR1 = '�';`

but when I use `$str =~ /^1(.{2})/; print Dumper($1)` I get `$VAR1 = ' ';`

I do it because regexps: `/^1\s/, /^1\s+/, /^1\h/, /^1\h+/` doesn't work.

How can I get a whitespace character rightly?

More info about the content of the string. If I do this:

```
print Dumper("1 Один");
$VAR1 = "1 \x{41e}\x{434}\x{438}\x{43d}";
```

but

```
print Dumper($str);
$VAR1 = "1 Один";
```

and with Useqq = 1

```
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper($str);
$VAR1 = "1 \320\236\320\264\320\270\320\275";
```

Comment: `/^1\s/` should have worked; what does $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $str; show for your example string?

Comment: `$VAR1 = undef;` with Useqq=1

Comment: err, then your string is not what you say.  did you use the right variable name for Dumper?  do you have `use warnings;` on?

Comment: I'm asking you to dump your original string, not $1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work with Unicode characters use `\X` instead of dot `.`

Regardless of Unicode support, the pattern `^1\s` is valid and works as supposed to.

Learn more about **[Unicode Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)**

---

You may need to fix encoding by

```
decode("utf8", $str)
```

or by setting

```
use utf8;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ only if the string were literally in the code; but it says "I get a string from an outer app"

Answer (score 2):

Data::Dumper is far more useful if you use `local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;`.

`$str` contains the UTF-8 bytes, but the match operator expects Unicode code points. You need to decode the contents of `$str`. It might be as simple as adding

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

(Substitute `UTF-8` for whatever encoding your terminal expects.)

Comment: If all you did was add `decode("utf8", $str)`, you probably still have lots of bugs.

Comment: Which one is it? From an outer app or from a DB? // Sure, I do, but I can't say much more than I already have without seeing what you're doing.